# how to save userdata using shared preferences

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: saving the user interests]

hello i am new to flutter, can anyone say how to save user preferred choice using shared preferences whenever the user opens the app the user choice should load with the app now the choice are empty when the app restarts  ......................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

follow the documentation of this package

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

```
 _save() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final key = 'my_int_key';
    final value = 'my_int_value';
    prefs.setInt(key, value);
    print('saved $value');
  }
```

This code will save your data to share prefs so you can read when you open the app next time. you might need to change variables as per your requirement.

Further you can read the saved data by:

```
 _read() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final key = 'my_int_key';
    final value = prefs.getInt(key) ?? 0;
    print('read: $value');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use package [Shared Preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)

This is how you can initialize preference object

```
SharedPreferences _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
```

And set data like this

```
_prefs.setString('key', value);
_prefs.setInt('key', value);
```

Get data like this

```
_prefs.getString('key');
_prefs.getInt('key');
```